# Rich Text Format Line Spacing

Tags: c#, rtf

I try to convert a plain text in RTF-Format. Therefore, I use RichTextBox (WinForms).
The concerned method the RTF-Markup as string.

Now, I want to insert line spacing in the markup. I found that there are 2 parameters:

```
 - \slX (Space between lines in twips)
 - \slmultX (either 0 or 1)
```

If I set `\slmult0`, the line spacing is **above** the line of text.  
When I set `\slmult1`, the line spacing is **below** the line of text.

I calculate the spacing in the following way:

```
(lineSpacing + fontSize)*20
```

When I switched from `\slmult0` to `\slmult1`, I determined, that the line distance is little smaller than with `\slmult0`.

Does somebody know the reason for this behavior? Do I have to calculate with another formula?

Comment: It might be simpler to go through something like docx as intermediate representation here as the tooling is better.

Comment: _I determined, that the line distance is little smaller _ How did you do that?

Comment: You can see it for example in wordpad: Create a new RTF-File change spacing to '2'. Then, save + close the file -> copy it -> change in the copy \slmult0 to 1 and compare both files in wordpad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*If I set \slmult0, the line spacing is above the line of text.
When I set \slmult1, the line spacing is below the line of text.*

That is not what I read in the [specs](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm).

The way I understand it, it means that `\slmult0` says that the value of `\slN` is to be used directly as a **distance** in some unit,  whereas `\slmult1` says the `N` in `\slN` is meant as a **factor** by which the regular line spacing is multiplied.

See the last post [here](http://www.trichview.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=442) 
for (some) more details! (But there is also a note about it taking effect one line too late..)

Also do note the importance of the sign of `N` in the `\slN`! (This was the reason of my comment above: The effect of, say `\sl234`, will depend on the size of the **tallest** character in the line..!)

[Here](http://search.cpan.org/~sburke/RTF-Writer-1.11/lib/RTF/Cookbook.pod) is a nice discussion of some things RTF; a note about units:

> Measurements in RTF are generally in twips. A twip is a twentieth of a
>   point, i.e., a 1440th of an inch. That leads to some large numbers
>   sometimes (like \li2160, to set the left indent to an inch and a half)

and a clear definition of extra spacing before and after paragraphs:

> \sbN -- N twips of extra (vertical) space before this paragraph (default: 0)
>   \saN -- N twips of extra (vertical) space after this paragraph (default: 0)

[Here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/rtf-pocket-guide/9781449302047/ch01.html) are more direct instructions:

> To double-space a paragraph, put the code \sl480\slmult1 right **after**
>   the \pard. To triple-space it, use \sl720\slmult1. To have just
>   1.5-spacing, use \sl360\slmult1. A single-spaced paragraph is the default, and doesn’t need any particular code. (The magic numbers 480,
>   720, and 360 don’t depend on the point size of the text in the
>   paragraph.)

Comment: Hi TaW, thank you for the prompt anser. I think, I have to clarify my question. I need the behavior from \slmult0 (distance), but the space should be below the line of text. Furthermore a question to the post in the link. What is the single line spacing in pt/twips ("\slN means that line spacing is N/240*(single line spacing)")

Comment: I have added a few more links and quotes to study. I would always expect the spacing to affect only the one paragraph you set it for, meaning the spacing __between all__ its lines. Did you set it before or (as recommended right after the \pard or (if you don't reset the paragraph after the \par))?

Comment: I've been experimenting with RTF line spacing, and I think the explanation on the Safari Books page is very bad. 480, 720, and 360 aren't magic numbers -- they're multiples of 240, which is the height in twips of the default RTF font size of 12pt. `\slmult1` says that the `\sl` value is a multiple of single height spacing. I would have expected to use `\sl2`, for example, to get double spacing, but what you have to use is 2 x 240. In combination with `\slmult1`, the rich edit control then understands that you want double spacing, regardless of the actual font size in effect.